# Filter 10k tools by a tag

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

It would be great to be able to look at 10k Tools separated / filtered by a given tag. When looking at the existing tools, everything is dominated by the popular topics like C++, C# and Java. It makes the review tools almost useless for analyzing and moderating less popular tags.

You can already use filters for review. This allows someone to focus on reviewing posts where they have expertise. Expertise in a topic always makes it easier to make moderation decisions. Similar benefits would come from adding that to the stats, migrated, closed, and delete tools.

Comment: even better allow the filter to filter out by tag

Comment: I want to be able to review based on my *favorite* tags (which I am fluent in), not the popular tags (which I know nothing about).